# Why does my bearer token not contain any app roles when using client credentials flow in a multi tenant scenario in Azure?

Tags: azure-active-directory, authorization, multi-tenant, azure-ad-msal, clientcredential

Using client credentials flow in Azure for app registrations that live in different tenants, results in bearer tokens not containing any app roles.

I created 1 app registration named "fake-web-api" in Tenant A for a web api and that app registration contains an App Role named "fakeAppRole".

I created a admin consent link by using the following format
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant-id%7D/adminconsent?client_id=%7Bclient-id%7D)

I navigated to that link and signed in as an Admin of Tenant B and approved the consent.

This resulted in an enterprise application "fake-web-api" to appear in Tenant B's azure active directory.

I created 1 app registration named "fake-daemon-app" in Tenant B and added an API Permission to "fake-web-api"/"fakeAppRole".

I created a client secret for the "fake-daemon-app".

Now the code that I used to test this example is in here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/2-Call-OwnApi

This example works perfectly fine for single tenant scenario, but when I tried to get it to work for muilti tenant scenario, I run into the problem that the bearer token that is returned to me does not contain any app roles and is therefor rejected by the "fake-web-api".

I expected the token that was returned to me to contain app roles, because it did contain app roles in the single tenant scenario.

Comment: Did you do admin consent for "fake-daemon-app"?

Comment: Yes, I gave admin consent from Tenant B inside the app registration “fake-daemon-app” to the api permission “fake-web-api”/“fakeAppRole”

Comment: Can you show how you are acquiring the token?

Comment: `var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("CLIENT_ID_OF_fake-deamon-app").WithClientSecret("CLIENT_SECRET_OF_fake-daemon-app").WithAuthority(new Uri("TENANT_A_DOMAIN_NAME")).Build();`


`string[] scopes = new string[] { "TENANT_A_Application_ID_URI_/_.default" };`


`var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();`

You can also check the code on the link in the original question it's exactly the same code as from the example, just with different appsettings

Comment: You've assigned the app roles in tenant B. They won't work if you acquire a token for tenant A. In that case the app roles would need to be assigned inside tenant A.

Comment: @juunas I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. I have assigned an app role to "fake-web-api" in Tenant A called "fakeAppRole" and I have added an Api Permission in Tenant B on "fake-daemon-app" to "fake-web-api"/"fakeAppRole". Could you please explain to me which part of what I did is incorrect?

Comment: It looks to me that you are assigning app role in Tenant B to the daemon app. This will only show up if you acquire a token from tenant B for the API using the daemon app's credentials.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249397/discussion-between-selmir-aljic-and-juunas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the issue turned out to be using Tenant A as the authority here:

```
.WithAuthority(new Uri("TENANT_A_DOMAIN_NAME"))
```

Since the app role was assigned in tenant B, we must use tenant B as the authority to see the role in the token.